# Two clients behind NAT on a single VPN connection, exting on two separate public IPs

Tags: networking, iptables, vpn, nat, forwarding

I am looking for a way to forward outgoing traffic on separate IPv4 addresses for different clients connected through the same VPN tunnel, behind NAT.

Right now I am forwarding port 44158 from multiple public IPv4 addresses on VPS server X to multiple clients connected through a single VPN connection - from a router behind NAT. The input port 44158 on the receiving public IPv4 addresses cannot be changed, and the clients behind the router receive the data on the correct port 44158 since the router is set up to forward to the correct port for each client at the destination.

This is done like so:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 103.143.72.84 -p tcp --dport 44158 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.52.2:44158
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 103.143.72.25 -p tcp --dport 44158 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.52.2:44159
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.52.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

Where `192.168.0.2` is the router at the destination which forwards packets to its internal NAT to the clients, from `44158` to `192.168.0.12:44158` and from `44159` to `192.168.0.13:44158`.

What am I trying to achieve is to make all outbound traffic from 192.168.0.12 exit through 103.143.72.84, and all outbound traffic from 192.168.0.13 exit through 103.143.72.25.
Is there a way to do this with `iptables` on VPS server X ?

I have this hardware setup which I cannot change, Clients A (192.168.0.12) & B (192.168.0.13) connect to router N on LAN and are on a NAT network 192.168.0.0/24. Router N connects through a VPN to VPS server X and obtains IP 192.168.52.2. Server X has multiple IPv4 public addresses (103.143.72.84 and 103.143.72.25).
And I would like to assign each client IP a separate outbound public IP on server X.

- IPs used are for example purposes;
- for the sake of simplicity I kept the example with two clients, but there are way more involved.

Answer (score 1):

Outgoing traffic use `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING ...`

And to specify source address use `-j SNAT ip`

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.12 -j SNAT 103.143.72.84
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.13 -j SNAT 103.143.72.25
```

Note that these must be before global `MASQUERADE` if you have it for that range.

If all IPs are linear ranges then there is other ways to NAT the range.

Comment: Thank you! Already tried `POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.12  -j SNAT --to (and --to source) 103.143.72.84`, but this does not work because `192.168.0.0/24` is behind 192.168.52.2 (the IP assigned to the VPN client router), so the VPS server doesn't see that network outright. I suspect it might work using conntrack ctorigsrc, but for the life of me I cannot figure it out.

Comment: The -j MASQUERADE at the end of POSTROUTING forwards everything coming from 192.168.52.2, all IPs behind the router in 192.168.0.0/24, through a single external IPv4 address. I put the SNAT before that, but it does not catch anything, 192.168.0.12 is not in the same network, but behind a NAT of 192.168.52.2.

Comment: Then your VPN router sees both clients as a single client `192.168.52.2`. Is there a way for the VPN router to identify and distungush clients reliably? Can you give them stable ("static") different IP addresses? E.g. remove NAT from the 192.168.52.2 system and set up proper routes, so the VPN router with public addresses will see and distingush them as 192.168.0.12 and .13 directly, or at least NAT them into different IPs, not into one 192.168.52.2.

Comment: You most certainly need to remove NAT from the VPN device in that case, unless you can do SNAT there already